# In safari browser a[rel='fct'].click function not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

A java-script function not working on safari Browser
JavaScript code:

```
$(function() {
    $("a[rel='fct']").click(function(e) {

    pageurl = $(this).attr('href');
    var path = pageurl.split('?')[0];


    // to get the ajax content and display in div with id 'content'
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : pageurl,
        success : function(data) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });


    e.preventDefault()
});
```

});

HTML Code :-

```
<a rel="fct" href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Stack Overflow </a>
```

Above code is working well in chrome,mozillabut not working in safari

Please help.
Thank you

Comment: Define *"not working"*. `//code here` not being called? Presumably Safari on Mac? Can you reproduce in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com)

Comment: I created a JSFiddle and it seems to work on my Safari (http://jsfiddle.net/Ljjat4og/) ... Which version of safari are you trying with ? Should not have an impact. What about some crapy cache of your files ... Safari is good at it :D

Comment: its not hitting to a javascript function.. safari version 5.1.7 for windows 8

Comment: It's working well for me. Anyway, I recommend you to use `.on('click', function(){ })` instead of `.click(function(){ })`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.. but now i have another error .. how to check contains function .. because now this string  .contains() not working in safaroi

Comment: Apple discontinued Safari for Windows in 2012, and it has not been updated since. I personally wouldn't focus much on fixing errors for it, and focus on the other browsers/platforms. As long as the code is working fine for them, it should be fine.